# How are images stored on the hard drive of an iPhone?

Tags: iphone

If I were to examine my iPhone's hard drive, in what format would I find the images in the Photos app stored?

Are they in a big `.sqlite` database file? Or are they stored as individual files such as `.jpg`?

I'm looking for the extension used (e.g. `.sqlite`, `.png`, `.jgp`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

All the images are stored as jpegs in various locations. The camera roll, for example, is stored in /private/var/mobile/Media/ (unless they've moved it).